# Twitter Bootstrap : collapsible table line width with colspan

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to use the collapse functionality in Twitter Bootstrap in order to display an additional line in a table with a single cell taking the whole width of the table... The line is displayed when a button in the above line is clicked.

The problem is : without the collapse functionality, with the `colspan` attribute, the "extra line" has the good width, but with the functionality in action, the `colspan` attribute doesn't seem take effect, the line stays of the width of the first cell of the line above.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>content</th>
            <th>content</th>
            <th>content</th>
            <th>content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible">Develop</button>
            </td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="collapsible" class="collapse">
            <td colspan="5">
                Collapsible content
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting a `div` in the cell that I want to collapse and attached the class `collapsible` to it.

Comment: Could you show us an example. I'm having the same problem - when the callapse class is added to the table row, colspan no longer workds.

Comment: I have solved this for myself using the $.collapse() function against the ".collapse" table row rather than swapping the "in" and "out" clases over. In my case, odd rows were the clickable regions and even rows were the collapsing regions. Clicking each odd row then applies $.collapse('toggle') on the following row. This did not affect the way colspan worked.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other solutions on this page worked for me, but
I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939080/2378910

(I don't want to take credit so upvote that one instead!)

It says:

> To collapse a table row, you should write extra css for the collapsed
>   row:

```
table .collapse.in {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

> It will fix the display issue after the row expanded.