# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Collapsing Rows Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to make a table that has rows that could expand and collapse on the press of a button, like in Windows Explorer, pressing the "plus" next to the folder will open the files in the directory.

Here's what I wrote:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head lang="en">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/bootstrap.min.css"       type="text/css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/trax.css" type="text/css" />
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Test Results</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-7 text-left">Name</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-right">Success</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-right">Total</th>
                                <th class="col-md-1 text-right">Fail</th>
                                <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Trend</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-        xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".module,.first">
                                        +
                                    </button>
                                    Foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right up"><span class="glyphicon    glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>80%</td>
                                <td class="text-right">5</td>
                                <td class="text-right">1</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span class="inlinesparkline"    values="1,2,8,4,5,7,10"></span></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="collapse out module first">
                                <td class="text-left col-md-7">Hi</td>
                                <td class="text-right up col-md-1"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>95%</td>
                                <td class="text-right col-md-1">5</td>
                                <td class="text-right col-md-1">1</td>
                                <td class="text-center col-md-2"><span    class="inlinesparkline" values="1,2,3,4,5"></span></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Bar</td>
                                <td class="text-right down"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>60%</td>
                                <td class="text-right">5</td>
                                <td class="text-right">2</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span class="inlinesparkline"   values="10,5,7,12,6,4,2"></span></td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="../asset/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">        </script>
            <script src="../asset/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../asset/js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript">        </script>
            <script src="../asset/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So, I managed to get the button to show a new row but it isn't arranged properly: the table cells don't arrange according to the table header cells like in other rows. 
But when the button is pressed, during the transition, it arranges itself right before adjusting back to the wrong spacing.

Adding `col-md-(number)` to the cells as classes doesn't fix it.

Please tell me how to fix it / where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That is a funny one. [I found a similar question with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628448/bootstrap-collapse-within-table-between-table-rows-not-working-rails/21939080#21939080) that appears to work. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwKw6/) that shows it working. Basically it involves adding your own CSS class that overrides the bootstrap CSS and forces it to display as a table row.

```
table .collapse.in {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

I can't say I particularly like the solution, especially the use of `!important`, but it works. There is anohter solution in the question I linked you to which involved adding a `<div>` to the `<tr>` with a class of *collapsible* but I disliked the sound of that even more.

Comment: It works in the jsFiddle you created but not when I copy it and put it as an HTML page and run it on browsers (Chrome and Firefox). I copied and pasted your exact code

Comment: Could you post exactly what you put where, perhaps in your question as an edit. Otherwise all I can suggest is checking it in Firebug or other developer tools and see if the class is actually being used or whether it is being overridden by something else